# SQL : CASE statements in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, t-sql

Table_1 is a simple table.

```
   Id   desc
  ----------
    109 xxx
    110 yyy
    120 zzz
    111 xyz
    121 null
```

the select query as follows...

```
declare @req varchar(max);

set @req = 'xxx';
--  set @req = null;

if (@req is null) 
BEGIN
   select *from [dbo].[Table_1] where isNull([desc],'')='' 
END
else 
BEGIN
   select *from [dbo].[Table_1] where [desc] in (@req) 
END
```

can we achieve the same result by saying those conditions in WHERE clause itself...?

I tried the following queries... both ended up wrong data.

```
select *from [dbo].[Table_1] where ([desc] in (case when @req is not null then @req end) or [desc] is null)
```

And this

```
select *from [dbo].[Table_1] where [desc] in ( case when @req is null then isNull([desc],'') else @req end)
```

Update: The `IN clause` is mandatory so that we can use `select * from STRING_SPLIT(@req, ',')`
The 
`@req` will be either `'xxx,yyy'` or `null`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `case` EXPRESSION.  Just simple logic:

```
select t.*
from [dbo].[Table_1]
where (@req is null and ([desc] is null or desc = '') ) or
      (@req = [desc])
```

The `in (@req)` is misleading and equivalent to `=`.  `@req` cannot be multiple values so `in` is not appropriate.

As you can tell from your code, `desc` is a bad name for a column because it is a SQL keyword -- order with `order by`.  Avoid keywords and reserved words for identifiers.

Comment: I just updated the question... Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @MK88 . . . You can replace `@req = [desc]` with `desc = string_split(@req, ',')`, if you like.  That is not what is in your original code, though.